# What happens if I subscribe to the same topic multiple times? (Python, Google Pubsub)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

If I have the following code, will anything bad happen? Will it try to create new subscriptions? Is `subscribe` an idempotent operation?

```py
subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()

def f(msg):
    print(msg.data)
    print(msg)
    msg.ack()

def create_subscriptions():
  restults = [] # some sql query
  for result in results:
    path = self.subscriber.subscription_path('PROJECT', result)
    subscriber.subscribe(self.path, callback=f)

while True:
    time.sleep(60)
    create_subscriptions()
```

I need to be able to update my subscriptions based on when people create new ones. Is there any problem with this approach?

Comment: The doc for this API doesn't say if subscribing multiple times to a particular path within a single program is idempotent?  Can you just try it...subscribe to a topic multiple times and then see if you get duplicate messages?

Comment: I mean, I tried it. I don't get the message twice or anything, but not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid repeatedly calling “subscribe” for the same subscription -- even though you will most likely not increase the number of duplicate messages that are delivered, you would create multiple instances of the receiving infrastructure. This is both inefficient, and defeats some of the flow control properties that Pub/Sub provides, since these are only computed per instance of the subscriber; i.e. it can cause your subscriber job to run out of memory and fail, for example.

Instead, I would suggest keeping track of which subscribers you’ve already created. Note that the “subscribe” method returns a future that you can use for this purpose, or to cancel the message receiving when necessary. You can find more details on the [documentation](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/pubsub/subscriber/index.html#subscription-callbacks).

Comment: What do you mean by "receiving infrastructure"? I feel that's the part from the documentation that's missing. For example, it seems that while using this in a Django project, a new database connection is created for every single subscription created which is unexpected.

Comment: "Receiving infrastructure" in this context means the classes in the client library that manage connections to the server (and the connections themselves) and manage the lifetime of messages received by the subscriber client.